# RegEx for matching repeated content in block between HTML tags

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to use a regex to take HTML like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>text1 (<a href="https://link1">link</a>)</li>
    <li>text2 (<a href="https://link2">link</a>)</li>
    <li>text3 (<a href="https://link3">link</a>)</li>
</ul>
```

And turn it into an ASCII variant like this:

```
• text1 https://link1
• text2 https://link2
• text3 https://link3
```

My current Regex is this:

```
/s/r/<li>(.*?)(?= \(<) \(<a href=\"(.*?(?=\"))\">link<\/a>\)<\/li>/• \1 \2/
```

It works fine for the core links, but I can't figure out to repeat that pattern and scrub the opening and closing  tags. I tried grouping it in +[], but that didn't work.

Can anyone assist? And yes, I know my current Regex code is terrible.

Comment: Obligatory: [**TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610) --- Whilst it *may* be possible to achieve this for your limited data set, it's never a good idea to rely on regex to parse generic HTML. The "right" way to do this is with an HTML parser.

Comment: Agree, however, on same thread, second answer with almost 3K votes: `While it is true that asking regexes to parse arbitrary HTML is like asking a beginner to write an operating system, it's sometimes appropriate to parse a limited, known set of HTML.` I should have warned OP, although

Comment: Oh, I know that it's not a good idea to, in general, parse HTML with a regex, but this is a limited case with a small set of fixed tags that won't change. Not sure why the question got voted down, nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some HTML parser.

If you want to go on with regular expressions, you may try this:

`(?:<ul[^>]*>|<\/li>)\s*<li>(\w+)\s*.*?href="([^"]+)".*?(?=<\/li>)(?:<\/li>\s*<\/ul>)?`

Replace by `• $1 https://$2\n`

See **[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rRq9Xs/1/)**

**Explained**

```
(?:                     # Will start with either
    <ul[^>]*>           # <ul...> or...
  | <\/li>              # closing li (</li>)
)
\s*                     # 0 or more spaces
<li>                    # literal '<li>'
  (\w+)\s*.*?           # Capture the text of the <li>, 
                        # then spaces, any character ungreedy up to...
  href="([^"]+)"        # href="..." capture the content
  .*?                   # any character 0 or more, ungreedy
(?=<\/li>)              # followed by closing li: </li>
(?:<\/li>\s*<\/ul>)?    # It may be followed by </li>, spaces, </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That works perfectly, and the explanation is super. Appreciate it.